# change the console color in c++

Tags: c++, colors, codeblocks

I have code blocks 12.11. During a program I have changed colour of the console with this code:

```
    setColor(8 , 15) ;
```

after this code the colour of the console has changed to grey, Even in other programs.
Then I uninstalled code blocks and installed it again but again I have this problem.
I think I have changed code blocks default .can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on Windows or on Linux? What operating system do you use?

Comment: Do you want to change it back manually or from code?

Comment: @ShT Please try `setColor(0, 15)`. Preparing an answer...

Comment: I want to change it manually

Comment: I have tried setColor(0,15); but I have the problem again

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958894/c-creating-a-change-console-colors-function?rq=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `setColor()` arguments are numbers that represent color constants:

```
+--------------+-----+
| BLACK        | 0   |   
| BLUE         | 1   |   
| GREEN        | 2   |   
| CYAN         | 3   |   
| RED          | 4   |   
| MAGENTA      | 5   |   
| BROWN        | 6   |   
| LIGHTGREY    | 7   |   
| DARKGREY     | 8   |   
| LIGHTBLUE    | 9   |   
| LIGHTGREEN   | 10  |
| LIGHTCYAN    | 11  |
| LIGHTRED     | 12  |
| LIGHTMAGENTA | 13  |
| YELLOW       | 14  |
| WHITE        | 15  |
| BLINK        | 128 |
+--------------+-----+
```

You see that `8` is `DARKGRAY` and `15` is `WHITE`. So, if you want to set background color as **black** and the text color to **white** you will run:

```
setColor(0, 15);
```

---

If you are on Windows:

1. Open a command-prompt
2. Right-click the titlebar or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
3. Select *Defaults* from the context-menu
4. Set the properties you would like (colors on the *Colors* tab)
5. Click **OK**

> The method that Tapped-Out gave works because Windows 7 happens to have [a bug](https://superuser.com/questions/323059/temporarily-changing-console-properties-in-windows-7) where the *Properties* option modifies the default values instead of just for the current console, and it could be fixed at any time. [source](https://superuser.com/a/429243/214156)

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately I have this problem again. I mean that when I write a new program again it becomes grey.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that even when I reinstalled codeblocks It happened again.